# Redirect from mydomain.com to CamelCase version (MyDomain.com) in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url-rewriting

I would like to url rewrite my domain, transforming *www.mydomain.com* into *www.MyDomain.com* (Camel Case version).

I added an helper in my ApplicationController:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    before_filter :redirect_to_camel_case_domain

     def redirect_to_camel_case_domain

       if request.host == "localhost"       
         redirect_to request.url.gsub(/localhost/, '127.0.0.1')
         return false
       end
     end
  end
```

It works fine if I redirect *localhost* to *127.0.0.1*.

Because the string in `request.host` is lowered case, it gets into a infinite loop if I redirect *localhost* to *LocalHost*
Same problem with `request.env["HTTP_HOST"]`.

I'm using heroku, so I can't use .htaccess

How can I get the real host of the request, not its lowered case value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Domain names are all case insensitive, and they are generally represented as lowercase. I think safari automatically "lowercases" any domain name you type containing uppercase letters. So this is what happens to you:

1. Point your browser to mydomain.com
2. Your server redirects to MyDomain.com
3. Your browser transforms it into mydomain.com
4. you are back to step 1

THe only think that can be case sensitive in a URL is the path component (everything after the first /)

Comment: Go to http://LocalHost:3000/ with Safari, and it will stay CamelCased. Though with Chrome, it is automatically lowered case.

Comment: Well this is not how safari 5.1 behaves on my mac. You will get problems with a lot of users on your heroku app, assuming it is possible for you to retrieve the non lowercase value of the request domain in rails.

Comment: Tested with Safari 5.1.1 on Lion. Point taken on the troubles ahead, thank you for the warning.